# Specify name or key for onPress in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am getting the following error in Expo: "You need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object as the argument."

I have a main piece of code calling the LoginOptions include:

```
<LoginOptions title="Don't have a business account?" link="Create a free account" press="CreateAccount"/>
```

I am trying to pass the navigation destination as a "variable?? - not sure what the correct word is". LoginOptions looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import defaultStyles from "../../config/styles";

function LoginOptions ({title, link, press }) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={defaultStyles.logBold}>
        {title}
        </Text>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate({press})} >
            <Text style={defaultStyles.logUnder} >
            {link}
            </Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
    );
}

export default LoginOptions;
```

Comment: which action do you want? Open new link in external browser or navigate to other screen in your app?

Comment: Go to another screen in the app please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass it as a prop of loginOption

```
 <LoginOptions navigation={navigation} title="Don't have a business account?" link="Create a free account" press={"CreateAccount"}/>
```

then

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';



import defaultStyles from "../../config/styles";

function LoginOptions ({title, link, press ,navigation}) {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={defaultStyles.logBold}>
        {title}
        </Text>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate(press)} >
            <Text style={defaultStyles.logUnder} >
            {link}
            </Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
    );
}

export default LoginOptions;
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, declare your screen in a StackScreen

[Guide here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation)

then, fix your `navigate` action:
`onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ScreenNameYouDefinedAbove")}`

P/s: I think you're using ReactJS routing' mechanism inside React Native. React Navigation has its own definition for routing, please follow the docs.